# .toUpperCase() is not a function

Tags: javascript

When name is all uppercase, then the function should shout back to the user. For example, when name is "JERRY" then the function should return the string "HELLO, JERRY!" The console logs error: .toUpperCase() is not a function.

```js
var hello = "Hello, ";

function greet(name) {

  if (name == null) {
    console.log(hello + "my friend")
  } else if (name == name.toUpperCase()) {
    console.log(hello.toUpperCase() + name.toUpperCase())
  } else {
    console.log(hello + name);
  }
}

var names = ["jack", "john"]
greet(names);
```

Comment: `names` is an array. An array has no such function.

Comment: That is an array not a string

Comment: Flagging as typographical error.

Answer (score 9):

`names` is an array. An array has no such function.

You probably want to call the `greet` function on every element of the array:

```
names.forEach(greet);
```

If you want the `greet` function to accept an array as argument then you *could* do

```
function greet(name) {
      if (Array.isArray(name)) {
            name.forEach(greet);
            return;
      }
      ...
```

but this kind of polymorphism is usually seen as a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified. When call greet("JOHN") then it will run however, when i call greet(names) then the console shows error toUpperCase is not a function. I want for both to run and not have errors.

Answer (score 6):

You could apply `.toString()` first, and then use `.toUpperCase()`:

```
if (name === name.toString().toUpperCase())
```

Comment: it's work for me

Comment: Can anyone explain why it works?

Answer (score 0):

`names` are array declaration so can't use that type of function, if you want print that array using for loop or using `names[1]` type

```html
<script>
  var hello = "Hello, ";

  function greet(name) {

    if (name == null) {
      document.write(hello + "my friend")
    } else if (name == name.toUpperCase()) {
      document.write(hello.toUpperCase() + name.toUpperCase())
    } else {
      document.write(hello + name);
    }
  }

  var names = ["jack", "john"]
  greet(names[0]);
  greet(names[1]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hello = "Hello, ";

function greet(names) {
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    if (name == null) {
      console.log(hello + "my friend")
    } else if (name) {
      console.log('toUpperCase works: ',hello.toUpperCase() + name.toUpperCase())
    } else {
      console.log(hello + name);
    }
  }
}

var names = ["jack", "john"]
greet(names);
```

If you pass an array into the function, it doesn't work. It's Better now.

Answer (score 0):

Since `names` is an array, you have to loop it first to get the value inside array. Or perhaps you can try my code:

```
var hello = "Hello, ";

function greet(name) {
    //loop name with for of
    for (let val of name) {
        if (val == null) {
            console.log(hello + "my friend")
        } else if (val == val.toUpperCase()) {
            console.log(hello.toUpperCase() + val.toUpperCase())
        } else {
            console.log(hello + val);
        }
    }
}

var names = ["jack", "john"]
greet(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, more ES leaning, with error and type handling:

```
function greet(names) {
    const hello = "Hello"
    if (!names){
        console.log(`${hello} my friend`)
        return;
    }
    // Handles a String
    if (typeof names === "string") {
        console.log(`${hello} ${name}`)
        return;
    }
    // Error Handling for Array
    if (Array.isArray(names) && !names.length) {
        console.error("Passed Array is empty")
        return;
    }
    names.map((name) => {
        const str = `${hello} ${name}`
        name == name.toUpperCase()
            ? console.log(str.toUpperCase())
            : console.log(str)
            // Optional if you have toProperCase as a prototype
            // : console.log(`${hello} ${name.toProperCase()}`)
    })
}

let names = ["jack", "JOHN"]
greet(names)
```

Results
[image: results screen grab]

This will handle an empty array, an array, a string and empty or falsy calls.  If you had a need to also handle an Object, it could be done as well with additional code.

**Bonus Material**

Avoiding a discussion on if using prototypes this way is good or bad,
just showing a reasonable way it could be done if desired.

toProperCase prototype:

```
String.prototype.toProperCase =
    String.prototype.toProperCase ||
    function (word) {
        if (!word) {
            word = this
        }
        if (word) {
            let str = word.toLowerCase().split(" ")
            for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1)
            }
            return str.join(" ")
        } else {
            // ERROR message
            // RETURNS var passed to it. If there is an issue it just returns the same value.
            console.log(
                "The util function toProperCase() \nis not able to do anything with '" +
                    word +
                    "' a typeof",
                typeof word,
                "\nReturning variable in same state."
            )
            return word
        }
    }
```